# How can I configure my home network to have everything behind one NAT?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet

I have the following setup in my apartment. I would like the desktop computer to be on the same network as the wifi. I also want the wifi router to be the primary router (it's an OnHub, and [Google's documentation](https://support.google.com/onhub/answer/6240987?hl=en) says many features are disabled if it is put in bridge mode).

- WAN connection in from FiOS, located in a closet
- ethernet connections to various locations in my apartment walls that meet in the closet with the WAN connection
- desktop computer attached to one of the ethernet connections
- wifi router attached to one of the ethernet connections

Right now, I could install a router in the closet, connect the WAN to that, then connect the desktop computer and wifi router to the closet router. In that configuration, I believe I would have to turn on the wifi router's bridge mode -- which would disable several of its features -- to enable e.g. my desktop computer to interact with my Chromecast.

I could also put the wifi router directly in the closet, and connect the desktop computer's connection directly to that, but I don't really want to put my wifi router in a metal box in the back of a closet.

What I want is to instead have the closet box basically force all of the traffic from the desktop computer to be routed by the wifi router as well, even though the WAN connection will go through the closet box.

Basically this, with the wifi router acting as the router for both desktop computer and wifi-connected devices:

```
internet <-> closet box <-> desktop computer
                        \-> wifi router
```

How can I set something like this up? Feel free to suggest hardware for the closet, I haven't bought a router/switch yet.

Comment: Why not use the LAN port on the OnHub for the desktop computer?

Comment: `ethernet connections to various locations in my apartment walls that meet in the closet with the WAN connection` sounds like there is already another router?

Comment: The OnHub and desktop computer are in different rooms -- I'd much rather use the ethernet wall jacks.

Re: "sounds like there is already another router?" Nope, there are wires run into the closet, but that's all, I have to put something in there to connect them.